# Get the taxonomy of the post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

How do I simply grab the taxonomy of a post using the post id? I have tried using the_terms and such but everything seems to require you know the taxonomy ahead of time.

Comment: Chances are there is no "the" taxonomy for a post. There are several. Are you trying to get a list of all of them? What? It isn't entirely clear what you want.

Comment: All I need is to find the taxonomy(ies) of post of a custom post type. It can output in any look or format and I can make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I need is to find the taxonomy(ies) of post of a custom post type.
>   It can output in any look or format and I can make it work

That being the case, what you need is [`get_object_taxonomies()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies)

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'post', 'objects' );
```

That will  not give you the terms in the taxonomies. You will need to loop over `$taxonomies` and [pull the terms out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms), if that is what you are trying to do. For example:

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'post', 'objects' );
foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) {
  var_dump(get_the_terms(1,$tax->name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$post_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'your_term');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms